# Remove Open Beta from Google Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I had an app in Alpha, that I wanted to get a bit more people to test. I set an open beta, and the app became searchable in the app store. I had some issues and the client wanted to go back to an close Alpha test and have the employees keep getting updates through the app store.

I can go back to the closed Alpha, but I cannot seem to remove the open beta track and the app is still searchable in the app store.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the open beta, create an empty release (one with no APKs on it) and publish it to the open beta track.

Note that I believe this will not prevent people who have already seen the app from seeing the listing. But they won't be able to install it.

Comment: Cool thanks. Will I be able to create Closed Alpha Still?

Comment: I don't see why not. But the docs now just talk about "open", "closed" or "internal" testing tracks. Alpha/Beta is whatever you use them for.